Puppeteer request interception affects total request quantity
Using puppeteer with nodejs to intercept a certain request during a website`s reload I noticed that some requests where missed by my script only when request interception was enabled, even though they were listed in my DevTools network tab.
This makes me wonder if this is an usual behaviour, which is to be expected due to the added latency to a request by the interception.
Using the attached script results in 22 requests (same value seen by recording the network via chrome`s DevTool) when loading and reloading the given website when request interception was disabled.
Having request interception enabled resulted in 24 requests during load and <16 requests when reloading.
Am I missing something?
Here is the script I used for testing:

/* package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "latest"
  }
}
*/
const puppeteer = require(`puppeteer`);

let requestCount = [0,0,0,0];  
let i = 0;
const url = "https://picsum.photos/";
const interceptEnabled = true;

(async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  if(interceptEnabled){
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  }

  await page.on("request", request => {
    if(interceptEnabled){
      request.continue();
    }    
    requestCount[i]++;
    // console.log(`url[${requestCount[i]}]: ${request.url()}`);    
  });

  await page.goto(url,{waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
  console.log(`Total requests load: ${requestCount[i]}`);
  i++;
  
  await page.reload({waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
  console.log(`Total requests after reload: ${requestCount[i]}`);
  i++;

  await page.reload({waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
  console.log(`Total requests after reload: ${requestCount[i]}`);
  i++;

  await page.reload({waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
  console.log(`Total requests after reload: ${requestCount[i]}`); 

  console.log(requestCount);

  await browser.close();
})();



Nitpick: await page.on("request", request => { should be page.on("request", request => {. The await is not necessary because page.on doesn't return a promise. I haven't investigated your main problem, but is it possible there is some caching going on?

Also, "puppeteer": "latest" is variable over time. I'd put your actual Puppeteer version so future visitors can reproduce it when "latest" points to a different version than it does at this exact moment.

I think improving the demo to show the actual URLs will make the behavior clearer.
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.6.0

const url = "https://picsum.photos/";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const requests = [];
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", request => {
    requests.at(-1).push(request.url());
    request.continue();
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    requests.push([]);
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
  }

  const uniqueFirstRequests = [];

  for (const url of requests[0]) {
    if (requests.slice(1).every(e => !e.includes(url))) {
      uniqueFirstRequests.push(url);
    }
  }

  console.log(requests);
  console.log(requests.map(e => e.length));
  console.log(uniqueFirstRequests.map(e => e.slice(0, 80)));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

If you run this, the final array printed consists of resources that were only requested in the first load:
[
  'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:600|Work+Sans:600|Open+Sans:300,400',
  'https://picsum.photos/assets/css/style.css',
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-T978ZC858K',
  'https://picsum.photos/assets/images/fastly.svg',
  'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/worksans/v19/QGY_z_wNahGAdqQ43RhVcIgYT2Xz5u32K5fQBi8Jpg.woff2',
  'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v40/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTS-muw.woff2',
  'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/worksans/v19/QGY_z_wNahGAdqQ43RhVcIgYT2Xz5u32K5fQBi8Jpg.woff2',
  'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v40/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTS-muw.woff2',
  'https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-T978ZC858K&gtm=45je4430v897008144za200&_p=17126',
  'https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/1035/536/354.jpg?hmac=N7LdfGCyj7EjI-_m2RvtgMrZ-SKgYmtwPBf_dd7ZDf8',
  'https://picsum.photos/assets/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png'
]

These are mostly fonts, stylesheets, analytics, an SVG logo and a favicon that the browser has cached and therefore aren't showing up in the request handler on subsequent loads. One request is a picsum photo that's randomly chosen and isn't likely to show up again after reloading.
In short, there's nothing unusual here, just the browser caching resources that the server has indicated don't need to be requested again.
You can modify the code to track the non-unique first requests as well:
// ...
    if (requests.slice(1).every(e => !e.includes(url))) {
      uniqueFirstRequests.push(url);
    }
    else {
      nonUniqueFirstRequests.push(url);
    }
// ...

Output of non-unique requests:
[
  'https://picsum.photos/',
  'https://picsum.photos/536/354',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/237/536/354',
  'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/536/354',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1084/536/354?grayscale',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1060/536/354?blur=2',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/870/536/354?grayscale&blur=2',
  'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSIjMUExQTFBIiB4bWxuczp4PSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYW',
  'https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/237/536/354.jpg?hmac=i0yVXW1ORpyCZpQ-CknuyV-jbtU',
  'https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/870/536/354.jpg?blur=2&grayscale&hmac=A5T7lnprlM',
  'https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/1084/536/354.jpg?grayscale&hmac=Ux7nzg19e1q35mlU',
  'https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/866/536/354.jpg?hmac=tGofDTV7tl2rprappPzKFiZ9vDh',
  'https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/1060/536/354.jpg?blur=2&hmac=0zJLs1ar00sBbW5Ahd_'
]

These requests include the root site itself, the shortened photo endpoints, non-random actual jpg images served by the shortened photo endpoints, and a base64-encoded SVG (probably a logo, I didn't look into it).
If you modify the code to clear the cache and cookies before each request, you'll get something like [ 24, 24, 24, 24 ], indicating that the cache was cleared and resources were re-requested every time.
// ...
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    requests.push([]);
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await client.send("Network.clearBrowserCache");
    await client.send("Network.clearBrowserCookies");
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
  }
// ...

